# Overridden aem OOTB journal component not getting css

Tags: aem

I'm very new with AEM. I'm using AEM 6.2 version. I overridden OOTB journal component from **libs/social/journal/components/hbs/journal** to in my project. I copied it and past into my project.

Then I changed journal component property  **sling:resourceSuperTyep:social/forum/components/hbs/forum** to **sling:resourceSuperTyep:/libs/social/journal/components/hbs/journal** in my project. Then I authored this overridden component on page. After authored it only displaying text boxes and buttons but not displaying any css design.

What I did wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Can you check for 404 errors in your browser for missingn css includes?

Comment: @i.net, Thank you for your response. I'm getting following errors: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)** for _italic_Resource at '/favicon.ico' not found: No resource found_italic_ 
and **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED**

Comment: That may be your issue. Try to load that resource in your browser and resolve the isssues...

Comment: @i.net, did I missed any tag library to mention in my project?

Comment: Unlikely. 404 suggests that the tig lib is included but it cannot be resolved. Check your clientlibds path or domain names or sling mappings and dispatcher mappings (if any).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely due to missing CSS includes evident
due to 404's you are getting in your browser's console. This may be due to one or more of following causes:

- Bad sling mappings.
- Bad dispatcher configuration.
- Invalid clientlibs path.

The clientlibs seems to be included ok otherwise you won't be getting 404s as the files would never have been referenced.

Answer (score 1):

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

This means your resource's URI cannot be resolved. Open the full link in a new tab in the browser and get more details on error. It is most likely a misconfigured path.